# What's the difference between in-place assignment and assignment using the variable's name again?

Tags: python, c++

In Python, while assigning a value to a variable, we can either do:

`variable = variable + 20`

or

`variable += 20`.

While I do understand that both the operations are semantically same, i.e., they achieve the same goal of increasing the previous value of `variable` by 20, I was wondering if there are subtle run-time performance differences between the two, or any other slight differences which might deem one better than the other.
Is there any such difference, or are they exactly the same?
If there is any difference, is it the same for other languages such as C++?

Thanks.

Comment: you already have half the answer in the title, one is in-place, ie no temporary is created nor are any copies involved, the other first calculates the result and only then assigns that to the variable

Comment: In C++ you can overload the `+=` operator independently of the `+` and `=` operators and make the sample code do different things. But don't do that :-)

Comment: For c++, the compiler has broad authority to modify your code in the name of optimization, as long as it doesn't change the observed behavior. As such, you would need to test for yourself, with your setup, with your use case and measure the performance, as it may vary. For fundamental arithmetic types, it generally won't make a difference. For class types, it depends.

Comment: "Premature optimization is root of all evil"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this can help you understand better:

```
import dis

def a():
  x = 0
  x += 20
  return x

def b():
  x = 0
  x = x + 20
  return x

print 'In place add'
dis.dis(a)

print 'Binary add'
dis.dis(b)
```

We get the following outputs:

```
In place add
  4           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  5           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 (20)
             12 INPLACE_ADD         
             13 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  6          16 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             19 RETURN_VALUE        

Binary add
  9           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

 10           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 (20)
             12 BINARY_ADD          
             13 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

 11          16 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

You could do a loop a thousand or so times using a timer to compare perfomance, but the main difference is that one. I suppose binary add should be faster tho.